# TableView moves down when fetching data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I scroll almost to the end of the current table view, it loads more data, and the problem is after `reloadData()` it almost instantly moves to another cell. For example, if I stopped scrolling on the 12th cell, tableView moves to the 15th. The same with 22 and 25 etc. I don't want my tableView to jump over cells. How can I repair it?

How I check whether its time to load more data:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "previewCell") as! postsCell

    let photosForFirstPost = photoURLs[indexPath.row + 1]
    //print(photoURLs[0])

    if photosForFirstPost?.count != 0 && photosForFirstPost != nil {


        let url = photosForFirstPost![0]
        // cell.imagePreview.kf.setImage(with: url)
        let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: photosForFirstPost![0], cacheKey: String(describing: photosForFirstPost![0]))
        // print(ImageCache.default.isImageCached(forKey: String(describing: photosForFirstPost![0])))
        cell.imagePreview.kf.setImage(with: resource)
    } else {
        cell.imagePreview.image = UIImage(named: "harry")
    }
    cell.separatorLine.backgroundColor = .blue
    cell.themeName.text = "Theme name"
    cell.readTime.text = "3 mins read"

    cell.textPreview.text = realPosts[indexPath.row].text

    if postsTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first?.row == realPosts.count - 3 {
        var arrayOfIndexes = [IndexPath]()
        for i in 0...9 {
            arrayOfIndexes.append(IndexPath(row: realPosts.count + i, section: 0))
        }
        requestTenPosts(indexPath: arrayOfIndexes)
    }

    return cell
}
```

How I request data at the launch:

```
func requestForPosts() {
    guard let requestURL = URL(string: "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=\(groupId)&count=\(howMuchPosts)&access_token=\(serviceKey)&v=\(versionOfMethod)&offset=\(offset)") else { return }

    do {
        self.posts = [try Welcome(fromURL: requestURL)]
        realPosts = self.posts[0].response.items

        searchPhotos(arrayOfItems: self.realPosts)
        offset += howMuchPosts
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

How I request for more data:

```
func requestTenPosts(indexPath: [IndexPath]) {
    guard let requestURL = URL(string: "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=\(groupId)&count=\(10)&access_token=\(serviceKey)&v=\(versionOfMethod)&offset=\(offset)") else { return }
    DispatchQueue.global().async {

        do {

            self.offset += 10
            for howMuchKeysToADD in (self.offset...self.offset + 10) {
                self.textOfAPost.updateValue("", forKey: howMuchKeysToADD)
                self.photoURLs.updateValue([], forKey: howMuchKeysToADD)
            }

            var forAMoment = try Welcome(fromURL: requestURL)
            var arrayForAMoment: [Item] = []

            for i in 0...9 {
                self.realPosts.append(forAMoment.response.items[i])
                arrayForAMoment.append(forAMoment.response.items[i])
            }

            print(arrayForAMoment)

            print("searchPhotos is called")
            self.searchPhotos(arrayOfItems: arrayForAMoment)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.postsTableView.reloadData()
            }

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if postsTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first?.row == realPosts.count - 3 {
    var arrayOfIndexes = [IndexPath]()
    for i in 0...9 {
        arrayOfIndexes.append(IndexPath(row: realPosts.count + i, section: 0))
    }
    requestTenPosts(indexPath: arrayOfIndexes)
}else{return}
```

or use simple else{} and don't forgot to give cell.tag = [indexpath.row]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the data, can you try inserting the rows at the bottom. Since you already have access to all the `index paths`, it should not be difficult and `table view` should not move.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //self.postsTableView.reloadData()

    self.postsTableView.beginUpdates()
    self.postsTableView.insertRows(at: indexPath, with: .left)
    self.postsTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: I have already tried to do it. Tableview still moves down for several cells

Comment: Can you share a video or gif??